Bash Script that zips a directory as "cert_$date.zip", then upload the zip file with curl to external server
I have a folder that I want to zip a directory, then upload it to a web server with curl.

Backup folder: /opt/ladapter/data
Zip File: /opt/ladapter/cert_$date_ymd.zip

Bash script:
cert_script="#!/bin/bash

# Variables
echo \"VARIABLES\"
date_ymd=\$(date +\"%Y-%m-%d\")

# Zip
echo \"ZIP\"
rm -f /opt/ladapter/cert_*.zip
zip -r \"/opt/ladapter/cert_\$date_ymd.zip\" /opt/ladapter/data

# Upload
echo \"UPLOAD CERT\"
curl --location 'https://my-api.com/upload' \
    --header 'Authorization: super-secret-password' \
    --form 'file=@\"/opt/ladapter/backup_\$date_ymd.zip\"'
"

echo "$cert_script" | tee -a /opt/ladapter/cert_script.sh
chmod +x /opt/ladapter/cert_script.sh
/opt/ladapter/cert_script.sh

This gives me the following error:
curl: (26) Failed to open/read local data from file/application

The zip file exists, but my guess is that bash does not find the cert_2024-06-26.zip file because of escaping inside quotes?

Why not use one of many backup programs that are available? Here is an example. Déjà Vu offers an intuitive, transparent, and reliable way to back up your data. It's a preference pane that lives in your System Preferences, and it allows you to schedule unattended backups of important folders, or even your entire system. With Déjà Vu, you can: Make a full, bootable copy (or "clone") of your disk.

It is not really a backup program, but a certificate service. It is easier to explain it as a backup program rather than mixing in certificates, SSL/TLS and what not.

An answer is only as good as the info in the question. Missing info equals bad answer.

You are almost certainly better off using a here-document rather than trying to stuff quoted strings within quoted strings. See for example Write a file in the middle of a shell script
